# OneupUploaderBundle: Files are not uploaded, why?

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, oneupuploaderbundle

I'm trying to upload files using OneupUploaderBundle and pretty much all is working but files aren't uploaded and I can't find where the issue is. This is how my `UploadLister` looks:

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PostUploadEvent;
use Oneup\UploaderBundle\Event\PreUploadEvent;
use AppBundle\Entity;

class UploadListener
{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $originalName;
    protected $tipoRecaudo3;
    protected $tipoRecaudo4;
    protected $tipoRecaudo5;

    public function __construct($doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function onUpload(PreUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $file = $event->getFile();
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $this->originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $this->tipoRecaudo3 = $event->getRequest()->get('tipoRecaudo3', null);
        $this->tipoRecaudo4 = $event->getRequest()->get('tipoRecaudo4', null);
        $this->tipoRecaudo5 = $event->getRequest()->get('tipoRecaudo5', null);

        $url = "";
        $deleteUrl = "";

        $response['files'] = [
            'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'size' => $file->getSize(),
            'url' => $url,
            'deleteUrl' => $deleteUrl,
            'deleteType' => 'DELETE'
        ];
    }

    public function onPostUpload(PostUploadEvent $event)
    {
        $em = $this->doctrine->getManager();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $productoSolicitud = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:ProductoSolicitud')->find($request->getSession()->get('productoSolicitudId'));

        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud = new Entity\RecaudosTramitesProductoSolicitud();
        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud->setProductoSolicitud($productoSolicitud);
        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud->setArchivo($this->originalName);

        if ($this->tipoRecaudo3 !== null)
        {
            $recaudosTramiteId = $this->tipoRecaudo3;
        } else if ($this->tipoRecaudo4 !== null)
        {
            $recaudosTramiteId = $this->tipoRecaudo4;
        } elseif ($this->tipoRecaudo5 !== null)
        {
            $recaudosTramiteId = $this->tipoRecaudo5;
        }

        $recadudoTramite = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:RecaudosTramite')->find($recaudosTramiteId);
        $recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud->setRecaudosTramite($recadudoTramite);

        $em->persist($recaudosTramiteProductoSolicitud);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

And it works since entities are persisted to BD. Now this is how my configuration for the bundle looks at `config.yml`:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        recaudos:
            frontend: blueimp
            storage:
                service:              ~
                type:                 filesystem
                filesystem:           ~
                directory:            %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/recaudos
                stream_wrapper:       ~
            allowed_mimetypes:     [application/msword,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,application/pdf,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text]
            error_handler:        oneup_uploader.error_handler.noop

            use_orphanage:        true
            enable_progress:      true
            enable_cancelation:   true
            namer:                oneup_uploader.namer.uniqid
```

And at Twig template level this is what I've:

```
<form id="cargaRecaudos3" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<input id="fileUpload3" class="fileUpload" type="file" name="fileUpload3[]" data-url="{{ oneup_uploader_endpoint('recaudos') }}" multiple />
</form>
```

And of course the component is initialized at jQuery level:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileUpload3').fileupload();
});
```

Any ideas why the files aren't uploaded? I'm using the same folder from within VichUploader bundle and those files are uploaded so permissions might be not the problem, any ideas?

**Edit**

I write a `die('meep')` as says [here](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/issues/101) and the response returns the die but file still not upload, any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First

If it is you first run of this bundle, there is a frequent error that all people do: **check if your folder `web` can be written**...

### Second

Try to make you config of the bundle simple like this:

```
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        recaudos:
            frontend: blueimp 
            enable_progress: true
```

Comment: As for the first solution that's not the issue I'm using that directory with VichUploader bundle and it works, and as for the second already tried no difference

Comment: is the first time using it, but for be the first time is not working, could yo help me to get this solved? Should we go through chat session if you can and after if we found a solution post here?

Comment: Did you know how to start it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66087/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-amine-jallouli).

Comment: I'm waiting for you please enter on the chat room on the link above

Answer (score 0):

Quick check of your code, I found a `#` missing in your javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fileUpload3').fileupload(); // the missing # is here
});
```